# MVC Partial View is not rendering correctly in main View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

**Question Background:**

I have an MVC partial view that is called from an ActionLink method and renders a dropdown list from the passed View Model. To add to this I am using the Twitter Bootstrap framework within this project.

**The issue:**

The partial view is not being rendered correctly - The button is justified to the right from what looks to be extra added HTML that is not present in the partial View HTML

**Code:**

The main view which calls the `Components` controller and the `GetComponents` method

```
  <div class="jumbroTronTop">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3><b>Files Release Page</b></h3>
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group">

                    //*****Partial View is called*****
                    @Html.Action("GetComponents", "Component")
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Codebase <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`GetComponents.cshtml` - Partial View:

```
@model ToolsReleasePage.Models.ViewModels.VMComponentNameList

<button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
Component <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="componentNameList">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>

@foreach (var component in @Model.ComponentNames)
{
    <script>
       //Call code to populate dropdown list.
    </script>
}
```

**Where the issue seems to be:**

Looking in the console in Chrome I can also see that instead of just the pure HTML from the Partial view it seems to be being wrapped in the following HTML - which I do not know where it is being added from:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Content/LoadingImageFavicon.ico">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title></title>

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

//Partial View Html
```

**I do not know why this HTML is being added but I'm sure the fluid-container the button is being wrapped in is the issue. How do I render the partial view to not included this extra HTML?**

Comment: What does your `GetComponents` action look like?  You are probably returning a `View` instead of `PartialView`

Comment: @BrendanGreen I can't believe I managed to miss that! You're 100% correct I had it set as a View and Not a Partial in the method. Please put this as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely returning a `View` from the `GetComponents` action, when you actually want to return a `PartialView`.

A `View` will render the razor file using the `Layout` that is defined (or the default `Layout`), whereas the `PartialView` will render the razor view without the `Layout`.